# Check nested JSON in Javascript/Typescript to see if Data is null before operation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Is there an easier way in Typescript/Javascript to check if nested JSON object is null, and then set a value? Right now, we have to peruse through 4 data layers to check if they are null, and then we can conduct operation to set value. Curious if there is any easier syntax?

```
if (this.addressEntryConfig
    && this.addressEntryConfig.addressModel
    && this.addressEntryConfig.addressModel.partyMailingAddress 
    && this.addressEntryConfig.addressModel.partyMailingAddress.address) {

    this.addressMailingInputData = this.addressEntryConfig.addressModel.partyMailingAddress.address;
}
```

Resource:  [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key/2631198#2631198)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Typescript, you can use optional chaining...

```
this.addressEntryConfig?.addressModel?.partyMailingAddress?.address
```

It will only return the value of address if the rest of the properties are not null or undefined. If any **are** null or undefined, it will stop processing and just return undefined.

If other words you can do:

```
if (this.addressEntryConfig?.addressModel?.partyMailingAddress?.address)
    this.addressMailingInputData = this.addressEntryConfig.addressModel.partyMailingAddress.address;
```

More on the TypeScript 3.7 release notes page here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: cool, I thought this chaining feature comes out in ECMA 2020 release, is it already released? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631198/12425844

Comment: If you are using Typescript you can already use it. In plain Javascript, though, optional chaining has not yet been added.

Comment: one more question, do I still need the If statement? could I just do      this.addressMailingInputData = this.addressEntryConfig?.addressModel?.partyMailingAddress?.address;

Comment: Depends what you want to set `this.addressMailingInputData` to. If you don't use the if statement, it might be set to undefined. Which might be okay for what you're doing, but that's up for you to decide.